# How to use a jQuery function as .ready() and .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a need to be able to change a `SELECT` statement using javascript and some other source of input (ex: drop down box).  I have spent sometime on the code in `removeOpt()` below.  However, I have had trouble getting it to work as a function and getting it to be called by `.ready()` and to run when `dropdown1` is changed.

There would also be a need for the function to retain the memory of the variables, specifically the `all_Opt` variable, since I need to be able to repopulate what is in it.  I've posted what I have tried below.  The `removeOpt` variable/function works when used directly in `.ready()`, but it doesn't seem to work quite right when put into a function, and not at all with the `.change()`.

---

In short, this is what I'm trying to do and need help with:

- Figure out of if the function removeOpt is valid, or find a valid method
- Have `removeOpt` run by both `.ready()` and `dropdown1` (using `.change()`?)
- Make `all_Opt` in `myFunc` static (trying the *closure* method)

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Java Script**

(*Note: lines with* `//CODE IN QUESTION` *were added after testing and validating that the code in the* `removeOpt()` *works in* `.ready()`*.)*

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  //Create 'removeOpt' function
  var removeOpt = $(function() //CODE IN QUESTION
  {
    var regex_str = "^" + $("#prefix_select").val() + "-";
    var dd1 = $("#dropdown1 option");

    //Clone the 'None', Current, and All options into respective variables.
    //All options are stored in order to allow different selection criteria
    if(typeof all_Opt === 'undefined'){  //Used if all_Opt is a static variable
        alert("defining 'all_Opt'");
        var all_Opt  = dd1.clone(true);
    }
    else{alert("not defining 'all_Opt'");}
    var none_Opt = dd1.filter(":contains(None)").clone(true);
    var cur_Opt  = dd1.filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().match(regex_str);
    }).clone(true);

    //Remove all options and replace the 'None' and Current options
    dd1.remove();
    noneOpt.appendTo($("#dropdown1"));
    curOpt.appendTo($("#dropdown1"));
  })(); //CODE IN QUESTION

  //Setup .ready() and .change()
  $(document).ready(removeOpt());  //CODE IN QUESTION
  $("#dropdown1").change(removeOpt());  //CODE IN QUESTION
</script>
```

**Dropdowns**

```
<!-- Used to limit options in "dropdown1" -->
<p>
<SELECT id="prefix_select">
  <OPTION VALUE="AB" >AB</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="BB" >BB</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="ABB">ABB</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</p>

<!-- Is produced SERVER side and cannot be changed -->
<p>
<SELECT ID="dropdown1">
  <OPTION VALUE=""    >None</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="1000">AB-Item 1 Description</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="2001">AB-Item 2 Description</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="50"  >AB-Item 8 Description</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="70"  >BB-Item 3 Description</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="100" >BB-Item 5 Description</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="2"   >ABB-Item 4 Description</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</p>
```

Comment: Since there's a downvote, any suggestions on improving this post would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass it. Don't invoke it.

```
$(document).ready(removeOpt);
$("#dropdown1").change(removeOpt);
```

---

And get rid of the `$(...)()` syntax.

```
// remove-----------vv
  var removeOpt = /*$(*/function()
  {
    var regex_str = "^" + $("#prefix_select").val() + "-";
    var dd1 = $("#dropdown1 option");

    if(typeof all_Opt === 'undefined') {
        alert("defining 'all_Opt'");
        var all_Opt  = dd1.clone(true);
    }
    else{alert("not defining 'all_Opt'");}
    var none_Opt = dd1.filter(":contains(None)").clone(true);
    var cur_Opt  = dd1.filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().match(regex_str);
    }).clone(true);

    dd1.remove();
    noneOpt.appendTo($("#dropdown1"));
    curOpt.appendTo($("#dropdown1"));
  }//)();
 //  ^^^--------remove
```

What you were doing was passing the function to the `$` function, which will pass it to `.ready()`. But then you were trying to invoke the returned jQuery object as though it was a function.

Comment: @the_system Thank you, this helps and runs (though the .change() doesn't, so I'll just us 'onchange' for now).  But I still need to be able to make the function 'static', so to speak.  The `all_Opt` should be undefined on the first invoke, but needs to be populated on the following invokes.  Is there a way to do that?  I was trying to use a closure method, but I'm missing some syntax.

Comment: @Phillip: To make the change event work, wrap that call in your DOM ready code: `$( function() { $("#dropdown1").change(removeOpt); });`. To make `all_Opt` a variable that is used for each invocation, declare it with `var` outside the `removeOpt` function, then simply reference it inside without using `var`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is incorrect.

```
 $(document).ready(removeOpt());  //CODE IN QUESTION
 $("#dropdown1").change(removeOpt());  //CODE IN QUESTION
```

You do not need to invoke the function here with `()`. Just do this.

```
$(document).ready(removeOpt);
$("#dropdown1").change(removeOpt);
```